# How to add a C# application for desktop AND a ASP.net application for web in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'd like to have a solution with multiple projects to deploy on my webserver. I have several web handler projects, but on the other hand I have a desktop application that, when deployed, will constantly run in the background of my system. I noticed that visual studio .net express for web does not allow user's to create desktop applications (visual studio express for desktop is required for such programs). I'd like to have everything as part of the same solution so that all the applications can connect with the same database.

Is there any way I can have both projects in my web application? Or alternatively is there some way to create an application in visual studio 2012 .net for web that can be run on the server and just do it's thing in the background while the server handles web requests?

Comment: You should be creating a service app, not a desktop app, if you need something that runs constantly in the background.

Comment: A solution can consist of several projects. There are no restrictions on what kind of project.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Ahh great, I see "wcf service application" in the list here. Is this what I need? I'll give it a try.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes that's what I thought, but it's not so. I am using a different version of visual studio specific for creating web applications - visual studio express for web. There is no option to create C# applications. When I installed regular visual studio express, I can't add my web application because apparently the project is incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that a wcf service application is quite what I'm looking for. So I will use regular visual studio to create my application and it will interact with my web application by making post requests.